# Checking permissions of a user that is in an AD Group within a SharePoint Group

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, sharepoint-foundation

I've been mucking around with checking permissions to a site (SPWeb) for a bit and it seems there is no straightforward way to do this.

The SPWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions doesn't seem to care about the person being in a group at all. So I've been working with something along the lines of this code, but haven't implemented any of the AD stuff yet. Am I on the right track here?

```
  private bool CheckWhetherCurrentUserHasAccess(String user, SPWeb spWeb, SPSite spSite)
    {
        bool hasReadPermission = false;
        ////Gets all the groups to which user is a member of
        List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> UserAccessGroups = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
        foreach (SPGroup spGroup in spWeb.Groups)
        {
            if (spGroup.ContainsCurrentUser)
            {
                UserAccessGroups.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(spGroup.ID, spGroup.Name));
            }
        }

        int id = SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser.ID;

        SPGroupCollection spGroupCollection = spWeb.Groups;

        foreach (SPGroup spGroup in spGroupCollection)
        {
            var checkPermission = from groupUserAccess in UserAccessGroups
                                  where groupUserAccess.Key == spGroup.ID
                                  select groupUserAccess;

            if (checkPermission.Any())
            {
                foreach (SPRole spRole in spGroup.Roles)
                {
                    if (spRole.Name.ToUpper().Equals("READ"))
                    {
                        hasReadPermission = true;

                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        return hasReadPermission;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

but what is wrong with:

```
SPBasePermissions.ViewPages
```

use it like so:

```
    SPWeb myWeb = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb();

    if (myWeb.DoesUserHavePermissions("DomainName\\userName", SPBasePermissions.ViewPages))
    {
        //does have permission to view page
    }
    else
    {
        //does not have permission to view page
    }
```

want other permission check:

full list here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spbasepermissions.aspx

its based on the spweb your passing! so pass the top level for spweb and it should work! if user is in group it should pass else if not fail!

so somthing like this:

```
        SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb();

        //can user current enumerate permissions.
        if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.EnumeratePermissions))
        {
            // Specify the permission to check. im checking pages
            SPBasePermissions permissionCheck = SPBasePermissions.ViewPages;

            // get user
            SPUser user = web.Users["login name string"];

            //get user login
            string login = user.LoginName;

            //check the user and weather they have that specific permission!
            if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(login, permissionCheck))
            {
                //user has permission
            }

        }
        else
        {
            //current user has no permissions for this web!
        }
```

the code above only allows users with permission to run this code! if not encapsulate with elevated priv like so:

```
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.OpenWeb();

            //can user current enumerate permissions.
            if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.EnumeratePermissions))
            {
                // Specify the permission to check. im checking pages
                SPBasePermissions permissionCheck = SPBasePermissions.ViewPages;

                // get user
                SPUser user = web.Users["login name string"];

                //get user login
                string login = user.LoginName;

                //check the user and weather they have that specific permission!
                if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(login, permissionCheck))
                {
                    //user has permission
                }

            }
            else
            {
                //current user has no permissions for this web!
            } 
        });
```

wrap the above code in a seperate method that takes a string for user name! now you call that method passing the user name ;) or loop though all SPWeb.users

Answer (score 1):

Your method of doing should be ok.

Things you need to keep in mind:
When iterating through a SPGroup, you will find SPUser objects
Even an AD Group will be see as a SPUser object.
NOTE: You need to make sure that the currently logged in user has the permission to iterate the SPGroup, if you do not want to open the group to all user, surround your code with the following:

```
    string siteStr = "http://mysharepointsite/";

//we just need to get a handle to the site for us
//to get the system account user token
SPSite tempSite = new SPSite(siteStr);

SPUserToken systoken = tempSite.SystemAccount.UserToken;

using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteStr, systoken))
{
   using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
   {
       //right now, logged in as Site System Account
       Console.WriteLine("Currently logged in as: " +
                        web.CurrentUser.ToString());

       //add your code here
   }
}
```

Comment: Or Run with elevated privileges